# I want Admin user to change the font, color and theme of a website from Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

what is the best way to manage this?
Thank You in advance for reaching out and trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done via `context_processor`, bit of logic and `SingleInstanceMixin` class:

```py
class SingleInstanceMixin(object):
    """Makes sure that no more than one instance of a given model is created."""

    def clean(self):  # noqa: D102
        model = self.__class__
        if model.objects.exists() and self.id != model.objects.get().id:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Only one object of {0} can be created').format(model.__name__),
            )
        super().clean()
```

The mixin above you can paste into `views.py` or `mixins.py` file. Then, you create `Settings` model in `models.py` file:

```py
class Settings(SingleInstanceMixin, models.Model):
    font_name = models.CharField(_('Font name'), max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(_('Color'), max_length=8)
    theme_name = models.CharField(_('Theme name'), max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return _('Settings instance')
```

You can create also function that creates Settings object when it's needed and populates it with default values:

```py
def get_settings():
    return Settings.objects.get_or_create()[0]
```

(You must define default values in Settings model then).

After all, you pass `Settings` instance to `context_processors.py`

```py
def website(request):
    return {
        'settings': get_settings(),
    }
```

Rest of logic you need to write yourself, in views, templates etc.
But the *initial* idea how todo that is shown in code I posted here.